# how am I supposed to use will-paginate with different sized columns?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, will-paginate

I want to achieve the following in a rails web app:

[image: Layout description]

In my image, 1 = @article.first, 2 = @article.offset(1).first

So for example:

```
ArticlesController

def index 
  @articles = Article.all.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 16)
end
```

Now how am I supposed to achieve this layout in the view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use (or not) of `will_paginate` (or any pagination, for that matter) is irrelevant to how you lay your visual elements out - that's the entire point of the MVC architecture.

The call to `paginate` makes sure you get one page of 16 results at a time, with the page number controlled by the `?page=` parameter in your case.

Elements are often laid out one after the other, which results in a formation using `.each`:

```
@articles.each do |article|
  render 'articles/article', :article => article
end
```

In your case, you may need to access the articles in the collection one by one, or even by index. `ActiveRecord::Relation` collections support array-like access, so to get the first of the sixteen elements you can use `articles[0]`, the second at `articles[1]`, all the way to the sixteenth at `articles[15]`.

Comment: So then I will have to write <%= @article.title %> 16 times?

Comment: @TimmyVonHeiss No, that's what partials are for.

Comment: I understand how to do this if I set the controller def index to @articles=Article.all and then in the view I do <div class="col-sm-4"> <%= render 'articles/article', :article => @articles.first %> </div> and then later <div class="col-sm-12"> <%= render 'articles/article', :article => @articles.offset(6).first %> etc etc but I do not know how I am supposed to use `.each`  to achieve this because the columns are different sizes.

Comment: @TimmyVonHeiss I never suggested you use each; read the answer again. `render 'articles/article', :article => @articles[0]` etc.

Comment: `@articles.each do |article|`... I don't see how I can use that code because I need different articles to go in different sized columns. If every article was going in a 'div class="col-sm-4" i could just do `@articles.each do |article| div class="col-sm-4" article.title`... since I have different columns, how can i use `@articles.each do`

Comment: @TimmyVonHeiss You're looking blindly in this answer for *some code, any code*. You can't just copy code and expect it to work. *Read* my answer - the last paragraph tells you about array access, which you can use to get hold of specific elements - like `.offset`, but within the paginated collection.